# CSS for Table headers,even odd rows?

Tags: html, css

My Table structure is like follows:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr class="navigation">
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <thead>
   <tr class="headers">
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="even">
    <td><a href="#"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
  </tr>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have defined following CSS ,how can apply "navigation","header","even","odd" classes in my CSS?
How to define them relate to 'table' class like 'table.even','table.odd' ?
thanks

```
table{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    #margin: 45px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}
```

Comment: You have a few errors in your HTML, such as an extra `</tr>` and two `<thead>` elements in the same table. There's also a random # in your CSS. I'm guessing those are just copy-and-paste errors though. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only reference the parent element's class or the parent element itself if you have to use the class name for more than one type of element. For example, this:

```
.navigation { font-weight:bold }
```

...instead of this:

```
tr.navigation { font-weight:bold }
```

It will cut down on load time when the browser renders the page.

Reference: [Optimize browser rendering](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html) [Google Code]

Comment: For the sake of future maintainability, atleast classing the table and using a slight bit of inheritance is a good idea unless you are 100% this is a global class.

Answer (score 9):

More simple and dont need class:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    put your style here...
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    put your style here...
}
```

I hope help!

Answer (score 2):

Applying a class to any element allows you to do the following:

```
element.className { rules }
```

So with your `TR`, you could do the following:

```
tr.navigation { font-weight:bold }
```

So creating zebra-stripes on your odds and event rows can be done like this:

```
tr.odd  { background-color:#FFF; }
tr.even { background-color:#CCC; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you would use

```
table thead tr.navigation {}
table thead tr.headers {}
table tbody tr.even {}
table tbody tr.odd {}
```

Comment: @devians, per my answer this is completely inefficient. You're better off to use .navigation for your table rows and if you have to define different styles on a different element, use a different class name.